# scanf doesn't work on online runners

Tags: c

I started learning C language yesterday and made a simple binary coverter. It works fine on my PC, however, it doesn't work on most online code runners(compilers) except for could9. It looks like the scanf function are not compatible with online IDE in general?

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

   int a;
   int b;
   int c[255];
   char opt[100];

   printf("10進数の値を入力してください > ");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("計算式を表示しますか? y(yes) or n(no) > ");
   scanf("%s", opt);

   if(strcmp(opt, "y") == 0){
        printf("\n計算式: \n"); 
   }

   int i = 0;
   while(a > 0){
       b = a / 2;
       c[i] = a % 2;

       if(strcmp(opt, "y") == 0){
           printf("%d ÷ 2 = %d 余り %d\n", a, b, c[i]);
       }

       a = b; 
       i++;
   }

   printf("\n2進数： ");

   int j;
   for(j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
      printf("%d", c[j]);
   }

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: You are not setting inputs? [DEMO on ideone](http://ideone.com/LZcUMF)

Answer (score 1):

My psychic powers tell me you are expecting these online compilers to prompt you for input (like running the program in a terminal window).  Unfortunately, this is not the case for most online compilers.  Instead, there is a text box somewhere where you type in *all* of the input that you want in your program's standard input.

For example, take this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

    printf("Gimme a character! ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    printf("You typed in '%c'! Yay! :)\n", c);
}
```

Compiling and running this in a terminal could produce the following in the window (input is in **bold**):

> Gimme a character! **f**
>   You typed in 'f'! Yay! :)

But running this in an online compiler that doesn't prompt you for input could look like this:

> Gimme a character! You typed in ' '! Yay! :)

By typing input into the text box provided (where it is depends on the online compiler) you can give input to the program that way.

STDIN:

> f

Output:

> Gimme a character! You typed in 'f'! Yay! :)